# Fixed string length only on text box not on the drop-down , c#

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have a below property:

```
[StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Port Of Loading Location Code must be of 5 characters.")]
public string PortOfLoadingLocationCode { get; set; }
```

That I set on a view conditionally with drop-down and text-box, something like below:

```
if(New)
   then "Bind property with drop-down" // Drop-down needs to be loaded dynamically that has more than 5 characters
else
   "Bind property with text-box"  // This must be of fix 5 characters length.
```

I have tried to put below data-annotation on the property

```
StringLength
```

But it doesn't allow me to submit when it is new and loaded with the drop-down.

Is there any way to resolve this?
[For reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6L61.png)

Comment: is this WPF? some webUI. Please provide more info.

Comment: @dba, it is not a WPF, It's been used in MVC razor view.

Comment: okay, then I'm out :-)